# Result always undefined when return the result Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

hi i got some problem here i want to return the result after getting target content on the getnada email, but its always return undefined, can somebody help me here.

```
const getEmailData = async (getExtention) => {
  //   return getExtention
  await axios
    .get(`https://getnada.com/api/v1/inboxes/${getExtention}`)
    .then(async (res) => {
      const getEmailCount = await res.data.msgs.length
      if (parseInt(getEmailCount) >= 1) {
        // console.log('Berhasil berhasil Hore')
        const getDataEmail = await axios.get(
          `https://getnada.com/api/v1/messages/html/${res.data.msgs[0].uid}`
        )
        if (getDataEmail) {
          console.log('Data berhasil')

          const getOTPEmail = await Promise.all(getDataEmail.data)

          return getOTPEmail
        } else {
          console.log('Data Gagal')
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      getEmailData(getExtention)
    })
}
```

here is the code of my procces on getting The content i want to get

but after i return the `getOTPEmail` its always undefined

the result i declare is like this

```
const getDataOTP = await getEmailData(getExtention)
console.log(getDataOTP)
```

can someone explain me whats wrong with this code ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the entire code, but you are not returning anything from the `getEmailData` function. Try to add `return` before the `await axios`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do it would be to move the code from the `.then` callback "outside" as follow :

```
        const getEmailData = async (getExtention) => {
      //   return getExtention

      try {
      let res = await axios
        .get(`https://getnada.com/api/v1/inboxes/${getExtention}`);
         const getEmailCount = await res.data.msgs.length
              if (parseInt(getEmailCount) >= 1) {
                // console.log('Berhasil berhasil Hore')
                const getDataEmail = await axios.get(
                  `https://getnada.com/api/v1/messages/html/${res.data.msgs[0].uid}`
                )
                if (getDataEmail) {
                  console.log('Data berhasil')
        
                  const getOTPEmail = await Promise.all(getDataEmail.data)
        
                  return getOTPEmail
                } else {
                  console.log('Data Gagal')
                }
              }
      } catch (e) {
        getEmailData(getExtension);
      }
    }
```

Also, you will notice that this part `const getEmailCount = await res.data.msgs.length` probably doesn't work as you would expect because length isn't a promise.

**But why isn't it working as is ?**

Using `.then` is using a callback on the promise return by `axios.get` so your `getEmailData` function doesn't return anything. It is calling `axios.get` which is asynchronous and provide a callback once the promise has been resolved, and leaving.

**Is there a way  to make this work using .then ?**

There is, with the following steps :

- initialize a Promise in `getEmailData`
- remove the `await` in front of `axios.get` call.
- call `resolve` from the initialized Promise in `.then` callback

Pseudo-Code :

```
const getEmailData = async (getExtension) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
     axios.get().then((res) => {
    resolve(res);
   })
  });
}
```

But it is way easier to write, easier to read and cleaner to use `await`, otherwise it's becoming a callback hell :)

Comment: got it mate your code work ill appreciate it mate, thank for your help, its work but i got a problem in checking the mail count ill search how to setTimeout before checking the email count

Comment: @Maszgalang you are welcome, do not forget to accept the answer (and upvote it) :)

Comment: how to repeat function after getting error ? @sorikairo the function is work well if the getEmailCount is 1 but if 0 the result is not return anything just console.log(success) https://prnt.sc/ww7g6l

Comment: @Maszgalang use a try catch around axios.get. I'm editing my answer to show it to you !

Comment: its stopped after return 0 https://prnt.sc/wwawjp, code https://prnt.sc/wwb0td

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is here

```
if (parseInt(getEmailCount) >= 1) {
        // console.log('Berhasil berhasil Hore')
        const getDataEmail = await axios.get(
          `https://getnada.com/api/v1/messages/html/${res.data.msgs[0].uid}`
        )
        if (getDataEmail) {
          console.log('Data berhasil')

          const getOTPEmail = await Promise.all(getDataEmail.data)

          return getOTPEmail
        } else {
          console.log('Data Gagal')
        }
```

because you defined the 'getDataEmail' variable inside the if statement and you want to use it outside it .
so ,I think you have to do it like this

```
let getDataEmail ;
if (parseInt(getEmailCount) >= 1) {
        // console.log('Berhasil berhasil Hore')
        getDataEmail = await axios.get(
          `https://getnada.com/api/v1/messages/html/${res.data.msgs[0].uid}`
        )
        if (getDataEmail) {
          console.log('Data berhasil')

          const getOTPEmail = await Promise.all(getDataEmail.data)

          return getOTPEmail
        } else {
          console.log('Data Gagal')
        }
```

Comment: Where is the author trying to  access getDataEmail outside of the scope it defined it ? For me it seems that it is always using it inside the right scope, even in your modified code, the declaration outside doesn't change a thing